# How to scale element in pixel with CSS?

Tags: css

Elements can be scaled with `transform: scale(sx)`, where `sx` is the (unit-less) scale factor. Is there some way to scale an element down by a certain number of pixel (without knowing its width).

**Edit**

I would like to resize elements of different sizes, like buttons, down when they are pressed. However, applying the same scale factor, say `scale(.95)`, on all buttons leads to the bigger (smaller) ones to be scaled too much (little). So, what I would like to do is resize all elements when pressed absolutely, i.e. by a certain number of pixel or em or so.

Comment: you need to ask your self how it will work with pixel? scale(5px) mean what?

Comment: You probably mean resize, since you're talking about fixed units or pixels, otherwise no, not with CSS (yet, hope so), would be possible if CSS vars could "accept" auto as valid/meaningful value and "store" its dims. for later use, then you could do e.g.: `:root {--w: auto} div {width: var(--w)} div:hover {width: calc(var(--w) - 5px);`

Comment: @VXp Thanks. Yes, I mean resize. And you mean not "otherwise" but "in that case", right?

Comment: Not really, in general, not just in your case, CSS can't do that, for now...what a pity.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. I.E. the attempt to scale by -5px is part of your solution to the _original_ problem. So can you elaborate a bit on what the original problem is?

Comment: @MrLister Good point. I have added my use case. Maybe someone know of a another way to solve it.

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643964/how-to-convert-css-pixels-to-css3-scale-x-y

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could scale the width using vanilla JavaScript

```js
const reduction=10;//in pixels
let button = document.querySelector("#myButton");
button.addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
  let style=window.getComputedStyle(button);
  let realWidth=parseInt(style.width);
  console.log(realWidth);
  let newWidth=realWidth-reduction;//some redundancy here
  button.style.width=`${newWidth}px`;//this changes the actual width property. With jQuery it would be even easier.
},false);
```

```css
#myButton{
width:300px;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Click here to resize</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I would know (with css only) is if you do the following:

> **This only works as long as it's width and height are not dependent on the elements content**

1. Surround the element you want to scale with an element that represents the  default size. This can either be set in pixels or as a percentage or whatever scale it choses (like auto)
2. On `:hover` use the css `calc` function to do `calc(100% - <number><em|rm|px|%>)` to scale it by any value and unit available in css.

```html
<div class="button-size">
    <button>
        Hover me please
    </button>
</div>
```

```css
.button-size
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
}
.button-size button
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 8px;
}
.button-size button
{
    transition: all ease-in-out .5s; /* easy animation if you need it */
}
.button-size button:hover
{
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 3em);
}
```